# "Greater Than" Operator in Racket with 3 Arguments

Tags: comparison, scheme, operators, racket

Looking at `>` in Racket, the following makes sense:

```
> (> 5 0)
#t
```

Why does the following evaluate to false?

```
> (> 5 0 0)
#f
```

Comment: Because `0` is not greater than `0` but equal.

Answer (score 8):

Because `(> 5 0 0)` is the same as:

```
(and (> 5 0) (> 0 0))
```

...Which is `#f`. For comparison, evaluate `(>= 5 0 0)` and you'll see that it returns `#t`.

Answer (score 6):

Pronounce `>` as strictly decreasing and `>=` as non-increasing.
Then it becomes easy to see that `(> 5 0 0)` is false.